# How to add left border on click of row in mdtable angular material2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular-material2

I am using [angular material2](https://material.angular.io) in my project. I have used the [table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) component. I want to add the left border to current clicked row only of the table.

There are hover and active selectors that I can use. But active selector keeps border only if the row is active that is only the time while the mouse is in clicked state. But I want to add it even if the user releases the mouse. How can I achieve that?

Comment: check the example https://jsfiddle.net/4vu6kzsh/

Comment: Thanks!! I am not using jquery.. any other way?

Comment: css con't do that, so you can use that concept to create that any other scripting language because i do jquery.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>` allows to add `class` and `event` to the whole row.

I added a `ngClass` in it to show `highlight` class when `row.id` matches with the `selectedRowIndex`. Also, added a `click` event to pass the row information to the component to set the `selectedRowIndex`.

Html:

```
<md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" 
         [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == row.id}"
         (click)="highlight(row)">
</md-row>
```

component:

```
selectedRowIndex: number = -1

highlight(row){
  // console.log(row);
  this.selectedRowIndex = row.id;
}
```

css:

```
.highlight{
  border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/EnPHAtqKFPAqiWVwLBqx?p=preview)

Comment: If there is not such thing as ID in my data, can I somehow identify row using some kind build in row identifier ?